# Automatically attach to process in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I have searched this site, and numerous others, looking for a solution to this problem. When I press F5 to start debugging my web app it will launch the default browser (IE in this case) with the web site. But if I want to debug the code I must goto Tools > Attach To Process.

In my previous job I was able to press F5 and the debugger would automatically start and I could step through the code, but I can't seem to do that here. To add to matters, there is someone else in the office whose also works as I would hope but he says he didn't do anything and doesn't know how to sort it.

I have tried numerous things, like adding `debug="true"` in the web.config but to no avail.

There must be a definitive way of achieving this, without having to resort to macros and the like.

Comment: Does this SO-answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911250/visual-studio-debugger-not-attaching-when-at-the-root-of-a-website/944947#944947 ?

Comment: No, the web.config does not contain a `location` node and the `system.web` node is a direct descendant of the `configuration` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out a workaround to get it to work...Don't know why this occurs, maybe someone will be able to enlighten me.

But I closed all other Visual Studio solutions I had open and now it debugs properly. It was actually a colleague who put me onto this as he was in a similar scenario and just tried a lot of different things.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: ...It has now went back to the previous problem. All I have done is add it to source control and it doesn't attach automatically again. :/

Comment: ACTUALLY...Upon further inspection, it wasn't if Visual Studio is open, it's if IE is open! (IE is my default browser, haven't tested with FF or Chrome as default browser and/or being open at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not related to the button itself but could be the preferences you chose on startup.  Go to Debug > Start Debugging on the menu.  What button appears on the right of the menu?

HTH.

Comment: I don't actually know what you mean. I have Debug > Start Debugging, but where should a button be appearing?!

Comment: Errr, sorry, I apparently had trouble with words yesterday :-)  What shortcut combo appears next to it on the right?  It says F5 for me, but different configurations use different keystrokes.